# Organizing list of tuples

Tags: python, algorithm, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples which I create dynamically.

The list appears as:

```
List = [(1,4), (8,10), (19,25), (10,13), (14,16), (25,30)]
```

Each tuple `(a, b)` of list represents the range of indexes from a certain table.

The ranges `(a, b) and (b, d)` is same in my situation as `(a, d)`

I want to merge the tuples where the 2nd element matches the first of any other.

So, in the example above, I want to merge `(8, 10), (10,13)` to obtain `(8,13)` and remove `(8, 10), (10,13)`

`(19,25) and (25,30)` merge should yield `(19, 30)`

I don't have a clue where to start. The tuples are non overlapping.

Edit: I have been trying to just avoid any kind of for loop as I have a pretty large list

Comment: Is it possible to have a list like `[(1, 4), (4, 8), (8, 10)]`?

Comment: Here's a quick and dirty idea: Set up two index-based for loops with second for-loop start from the index of outer loop. Check if you can merge tuples using index from outer loop, with the index of inner loop. If you can replace index[i] with `(a,d)`, and repeat.

Comment: Right, what should be the correct way to handle that

Comment: this is pretty easy. what have you tried

Comment: Since the tuples are non-overlapping, you can simply sort the list, then merge adjacent tuples if they coincide.

Comment: What do you do in case of more than one pair of mergeable tuples for instance (8, 10), (10, 13), (10,12). Which pair do you merge and delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

non-recursive approach, using sorting (I've added more nodes to handle complex case):

```
l = [(1,4), (8,10), (19,25), (10,13), (14,16), (25,30), (30,34), (38,40)]
l = sorted(l)

r=[]
idx=0

while idx<len(l):
    local=idx+1
    previous_value = l[idx][1]
    # search longest string
    while local<len(l):
        if l[local][0]!=previous_value:
            break
        previous_value = l[local][1]
        local+=1
    # store tuple
    r.append((l[idx][0],l[local-1][1]))
    idx = local


print(r)
```

result:

```
[(1, 4), (8, 13), (14, 16), (19, 34), (38, 40)]
```

The only drawback is that original sort order is not preserved. I don't know if it's a problem.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to take into account things like skovorodkin's example in the comment,

```
[(1, 4), (4, 8), (8, 10)]
```

(or even more complex examples), then one way to do efficiently would be using graphs.

Say you create a digraph (possibly using [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/)), where each pair is a node, and there is an edge from *(a, b)* to node *(c, d)* if *b == c*. Now run [topological sort](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort.html), iterate according to the order, and merge accordingly. You should take care to handle nodes with two (or more) outgoing edges properly.

---

I realize your question states you'd like to avoid loops on account of the long list size. Conversely, for long lists, I doubt you'll find even an efficient linear time solution using list comprehension (or something like that). Note that you cannot sort the list in linear time, for example.

---

Here is a possible implementation:

Say we start with

```
l = [(1,4), (8,10), (19,25), (10,13), (14,16), (25,30)]
```

It simplifies the following to remove duplicates, so let's do:

```
l = list(set(l))
```

Now to build the digraph:

```
import networkx as nx
import collections

g = nx.DiGraph()
```

The vertices are simply the pairs:

```
g.add_nodes_from(l)
```

To build the edges, we need a dictionary:

```
froms = collections.defaultdict(list)
for p in l:
    froms[p[0]].append(p)
```

Now we can add the edges:

```
for p in l:
    for from_p in froms[p[1]]:
        g.add_edge(p, from_p)
```

Next two lines are unneeded - they're just here to show what the graph looks like at this point:

```
>>> g.nodes()
[(25, 30), (14, 16), (10, 13), (8, 10), (1, 4), (19, 25)]

>>> g.edges()
[((8, 10), (10, 13)), ((19, 25), (25, 30))]
```

Now, let's sort the pairs by topological sort:

```
l = nx.topological_sort(g)
```

Finally, here's the tricky part. The result will be a DAG. We have to to traverse things recursively, but remember what we visited already.

Let's create a dict of what we visited:

```
visited = {p: False for p in l}
```

Now a recursive function, that given a node, returns the maximum range edge from any node reachable from it:

```
def visit(p):
    neighbs = g.neighbors(p)
    if visited[p] or not neighbs:
        visited[p] = True
        return p[1]
    mx = max([visit(neighb_p) for neighb_p in neighbs])
    visited[p] = True
    return mx
```

We're all ready. Let's create a list for the final pairs:

```
final_l = []
```

and visit all nodes:

```
for p in l:
    if visited[p]:
        continue
    final_l.append((p[0], visit(p)))
```

Here's the final result:

```
>>> final_l
[(1, 4), (8, 13), (14, 16)]
```

Comment: @Zanam There it is. It's not the shortest code in the world, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

If they don't overlap, then you can sort them, and then just combine adjacent ones.

Here's a generator that yields the new tuples:

```
def combine_ranges(L):
    L = sorted(L)  # Make a copy as we're going to remove items!
    while L:
        start, end = L.pop(0)  # Get the first item
        while L and L[0][0] == end:
            # While the first of the rest connects to it, adjust
            # the end and remove the first of the rest
            _, end = L.pop(0)
        yield (start, end)

print(list(combine_ranges(List)))
```

If speed is important, use a `collections.deque` instead of a list, so that the `.pop(0)` operations can be in constant speed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one optimized recursion approach:

```
In [44]: def find_intersection(m_list):
             for i, (v1, v2) in enumerate(m_list):
                 for j, (k1, k2) in enumerate(m_list[i + 1:], i + 1):
                     if v2 == k1:
                         m_list[i] = (v1, m_list.pop(j)[1])
                         return find_intersection(m_list)
             return m_list
```

Demo:

```
In [45]: lst = [(1,4), (8,10), (19,25), (10,13), (14,16), (25,30)]

In [46]: find_intersection(lst)
Out[46]: [(1, 4), (8, 13), (19, 30), (14, 16)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary to map the different end indices to the range ending at that index; then just iterate the list sorted by start index and merge the segments accordingly:

```
def join_lists(lst):
    ending = {}  # will map end position to range
    for start, end in sorted(lst):  # iterate in sorted order
        if start in ending:
            ending[end] = (ending[start][0], end)  # merge
            del ending[start]  # remove old value
        else:
            ending[end] = (start, end)
    return list(ending.values())  # return remaining values from dict
```

Alternatively, as pointed out by [Tomer W in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904161/organizing-list-of-tuples/39904621#comment67105721_39904621), you can do without the sorting, by iterating the list twice, making this solution take only linear time (*O(n)*) w.r.t. the length of the list.

```
def join_lists(lst):
    ending = {}  # will map end position to range
    # first pass: add to dictionary
    for start, end in lst:
        ending[end] = (start, end)
    # second pass: lookup and merge
    for start, end in lst:
        if start in ending:
            ending[end] = (ending[start][0], end)
            del ending[start]
    # return remaining values from dict
    return list(ending.values())
```

Examples output, for both cases:

```
>>> join_lists([(1,4), (8,10), (19,25), (10,13), (14,16), (25,30)])
[(1, 4), (8, 13), (14, 16), (19, 30)]
>>> join_lists(lst = [(1, 4), (4, 8), (8, 10)])
[(1, 10)]
```

Comment: Only one that induced a `O(N)` approach :) up.

Comment: so i might not get your answer, my thought was:
1st pass fill hash-map with `end val > section` then
2nd pass for each `start-val` find it's `end-val` in the `hashmap`.

Comment: @TomerW Did not think of that. I did the sort so the ending entries are already in the map, but just doing two passes is much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The list is first sorted and adjacent pairs of (min1, max1), (min2, max2) are merged together if they overlap.

```
MIN=0
MAX=1

def normalize(intervals):
    isort = sorted(intervals)
    for i in range(len(isort) - 1): 
        if isort[i][MAX] >= isort[i + 1][MIN]:
            vmin = isort[i][MIN]
            vmax = max(isort[i][MAX], isort[i + 1][MAX])
            isort[i] = None
            isort[i + 1] = (vmin, vmax)
    return [r for r in isort if r is not None]

List1 = [(1,4), (8,10), (19,25), (10,13), (14,16), (25,30)]
List2 = [(1, 4), (4, 8), (8, 10)]
print(normalize(List1))
print(normalize(List2))

#[(1, 4), (8, 13), (14, 16), (19, 30)]
#[(1, 10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work.  It breaks tuples into individual numbers, then finds the tuple bound on each cluster.  This should work even with difficult overlaps, like `[(4, 10), (9, 12)]`

It's a very simple fix.

```
# First turn your list of tuples into a list of numbers:
my_list = []
for item in List: my_list = my_list + [i for i in range(item[0], item[1]+1)]

# Then create tuple pairs:
output = []
a = False
for x in range(max(my_list)+1):
    if (not a) and (x in my_list): a = x
    if (a) and (x+1 not in my_list):
        output.append((a, x))
        a = False

print output
```